# Cascading dropdowns on Mediawiki site

Tags: css

This is my first post here. I am not a developer but have learned a bit about CSS the last few months. I have a basic Mediawiki site which has raw HTML enabled on the site which is a secure site and only a very limited number of users with edit privilege's.

I am trying to make it so that when a user clicks the "Submit" button on the HTML form for the cascading dropdown, it will take them to a specific section on a page, based on what they have chosen in all the drop down boxes. I have used the w3schools site to borrow some code snippets.

Here is my form:

```
<html>
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="Front-end#CSS#Backgrounds">
  Subjects: <select name="subject" id="subject">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select subject</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  Topics: <select name="topic" id="topic">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Please select subject first</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  Chapters: <select name="chapter" id="chapter">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Please select topic first</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</html>
```

And here is the java script I am using.

```
var subjectObject = {
  "Front-end": {
    "HTML": ["Links", "Images", "Tables", "Lists"],
    "CSS": ["Borders", "Margins", "Backgrounds", "Float"],
    "JavaScript": ["Variables", "Operators", "Functions", "Conditions"]
  },
  "Back-end": {
    "PHP": ["Variables", "Strings", "Arrays"],
    "SQL": ["SELECT", "UPDATE", "DELETE"]
  }
}
window.onload = function() {
  var subjectSel = document.getElementById("subject");
  var topicSel = document.getElementById("topic");
  var chapterSel = document.getElementById("chapter");
  for (var x in subjectObject) {
    subjectSel.options[subjectSel.options.length] = new Option(x, x);
  }
  subjectSel.onchange = function() {
    //display correct values
    for (var y in subjectObject[this.value]) {
      topicSel.options[topicSel.options.length] = new Option(y, y);
    }
  }
  topicSel.onchange = function() {
    //display correct values
    var z = subjectObject[subjectSel.value][this.value];
    for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
      chapterSel.options[chapterSel.options.length] = new Option(z[i], z[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

In my form example above I hard coded the action= portion to say *Front-end#CSS#Backgrounds*

When I click the submit button it launches or takes me to this URL:

https://*mysitename.com*/*myenvironment*/index.php/Front-end?subject=Front-end&topic=CSS&chapter=Backgrounds#CSS#Backgrounds

In the example subject = my page name, in this case Front-end, topic = my Heading 1 section, in my case CSS, and chapter = my Heading 2 section, in my case Backgrounds.

But it's not working fully. When I click submit it takes me to the "Front-end" page on my Mediawiki site but it doesn't recognize or do anything with the Heading 1 and Heading 2 parts.

The way this will be used is to allow the user to select the page and section of a page they will be going to. So that in a form using three cascading dropdowns, the user will first pick the subject, which is actually the name of the page on my Mediawiki site, the second drop down will be the Heading 1 section, and the third drop down will be the Heading 2 section which is where I want the user to end up on the page.

The Mediawiki page sort of looks like this:

Page name is "Front-end"

Table of contents is for example:

```
## CSS ##
### Borders ###
### Margins ###
### Backgrounds ###
### Float ###
```

I will have the HTML cascading dropdown forms setup with three boxes. In my example, the user picks Front-end -- CSS -- Backgrounds and when they hit submit they go directly to the Heading 2 section on my page for "Backgrounds"  Obviously, I need to code it so that whatever combination the user picks I take them to the right page section.

Any ideas on how I can do this? I would like to stick with the simple HTML form and Java Script example above as it is easy for me. Any advice is appreciated! Thanks in advance and sorry for the long post.

GJ231

Answer (score 1):

Well many things to check.. First of all.. https://mysitename.com/myenvironment/index.php/Front-end?subject=Front-end&topic=CSS&chapter=Backgrounds#CSS#Backgrounds

An url can jump to one Anchor. not two. So am I guessing you will need some more JavaScript on checking the Post url and figure out where to go to on the page depending on the Post url.

The content of the page would need to have Anchor links inside them, something like #-- e.g. #Front-End-CSS-Backgrounds

Then before you post, you should change the url to something like : https://mysitename.com/myenvironment/index.php/Front-end#Front-End-CSS-Backgrounds

That will bring the person to the right spot.

If you cannot create anchor links on the page, perhaps you can create divs with the same format Id's ? or Something similar. Then have JavaScript jump to the relevant ID based on the url.